# Linking SFML within CMake, compiling from sources

Tags: compilation, cmake, sfml

I'm trying to include SFML as a dependency in my CMake project, and it compiles SFML fine, but I can't figure out how to link it.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt, with annotated comments:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.1)
set(CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 1)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) # Set C++11
project(CHIP8)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib) # static library
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib) # dynamic library
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin) # executables
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

# Include SFML
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/SFML)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/SFML/include)

#Include where to find headers
include_directories(./src)
include_directories(./src/headers)

# Do a GLOB search, and add them to executable
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "CHIP8")
file(GLOB SRC_FILES
    "src/headers/*.h"
    "src/*.cpp"
)

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} SFML) #Here is where the problem lies!
```

As you can see, I'm adding the subdirectory `./dep/SFML` so it compiles with its own CMakeLists. Including the headers too on the next line, which VSCode picks up.

However, I'm having trouble on the last line: `target_link_libraries`. It can't find `sfml` `SFML` or `SFML2`. Therefore, I'm not sure how to link it.

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: SFML is not a single library, but a **set of libraries**, each of which corresponds to some *component*. Target for the library is named as "sfml-<component-name>". When use SFML in your code, you should know which SFML components you use (see SFML docs/tutorials).

Comment: @Tsyvarev It works. Do you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFML is not a single library, but a **set of libraries**, each of which corresponds to some *component*. For component named

```
<component-name>
```

the library target is named

```
sfml-<component-name>
```

When use SFML in your code, you should know which SFML component(s) you use (see SFML docs/tutorials), and link with corresponded libraries:

```
# Assuming you use "graphics" and "system" SFML components
target_link_libraries(<your-executable> sfml-graphics sfml-system)
```

---

Note, that such targets' naming is not officially documented, so it can be changed in the future.

Preferred way for link with SFML is to **install** it before (or during) configuring your project, and use

```
find_package(SFML REQUIRED COMPONENTS graphics system)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(<your-executable> ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```